# How to sort an object of objects based on the keys in descending order?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to order an array of object of objects based on the object's key.
How do I go about sorting a JSON Object that's already in ascending order? Please see below.

I've tried to convert the data value object into its own array, then sort it that way, but I'm getting syntax errors.

```
var object = [
A1: {
errors: {}
otherData: {}
data: {
  "1": {
    "name": "Ashley",
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "Cardiff",
  },
  "3": {
    "name": "Reading",
    }
}},

A2: {
errors: {}
otherData: {}
data: {
  "4": {
    "name": "Susan",
  },
  "5": {
    "name": "Bee",
  },
  "6": {
    "name": "Bob",
    }
}}];
```

I want it to be:

```
var object = [
A1: {
errors: {}
otherData: {}
data: {
  "3": {
    "name": "Reading",
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "Cardiff",
  },
  "1": {
    "name": "Ashley",
    }
}},

A2: {
errors: {}
otherData: {}
data: {
  "6": {
    "name": "Bob",
  },
  "5": {
    "name": "Bee",
  },
  "4": {
    "name": "Susan",
    }
}}];
```

Comment: Objects doesnot keep track of the order of keys. I would suggest you to use array of objects.

Comment: i have updated my answer, tailored for your need. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sortByField = (field, isRevered = false, primerFn) => {
  if (field) {
    var key = primerFn ? (x) => primerFn(x[field]) : (x) => x[field];

    isRevered = !isRevered ? 1 : -1;

    return (a, b) => {
      /*eslint-disable */
      return a = key(a), b = key(b), isRevered * ((a > b) - (b > a));
      /*eslint-enable */
    }
  }
  else {
    return (a, b) => {
      return isRevered ? a < b : a > b;
    }
  }
}

var dataToSort = {
  A1: {
    errors: {},
    otherData: {},
    data: {
      "1": { "name": "Ashley", },
      "2": { "name": "Cardiff", },
      "3": { "name": "Reading", }
    }
  },
  A2: {
    errors: {},
    otherData: {},
    data: {
      "4": { "name": "Susan", },
      "5": { "name": "Bee", },
      "6": { "name": "Bob", }
    }
  }
};

const sortObjectByKeys = (obj) => {
  let values = [];
  let keys = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    keys.push(key);
    values.push(obj[key])
  })

  values.sort(sortByField("name", true, (value) => value.toLowerCase()));

  let sortedObject = {};

  values.forEach((value, index) => {
    sortedObject[keys[index]] = value;
  })

  return sortedObject;
}

let sortedData = {};
Object.keys(dataToSort).forEach(dataKey => {
  sortedData[dataKey] = {
    ...dataToSort[dataKey],
    data: sortObjectByKeys(dataToSort[dataKey].data)
  }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedData));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to sort the in alphabetical order by first letter. This is kind of out there but it should do what you're looking for

```
const arr1 = object.map(function(o) {
     return Object.values(o[Object.keys(o)].data).sort((a, b) => a - b);
})
```

I'll try to explain what's happening here. `map` is iterating over each object in the array and return a brand new array. `o[Object.keys(o)].data` is selecting `A1` and `A2` data keys. Then we're saying we want the values of the objects in those data objects with the surrounds `Object.keys()` which is giving us the names. From there we're just calling sort and giving it the callback.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. But what I meant was that I want to sort by the keys in A1 and A2 in descending order. For example, A1 has keys 1, 2, 3. I want it to return the full collection with A1 having keys in the order of 3, 2, 1.